# Automatically running cygwin as administrator

Tags: cygwin, admin

On Windows 10 (Enterprise 64-bit), I often need to start cygwin as administrator, as otherwise it has problems interacting with Windows programs. I can set it to run as administrator via the compatibility settings, but this means a modal dialog is brought up every time Cygwin is run. Is there any way around this?